# how does phishing works for metamask?

Tags: solidity, metamask, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have read the following:

> Gene is working on his laptop with several tabs open in his browser.
> He unlocks his MetaMask wallet to make a transaction. An attacker uses
> the open tabs to see that Gene is using MetaMask.
>
> The attacker sends Gene a pop-up message saying that his transaction
> has failed. This happens sometimes, so Gene isn’t worried. He enters
> his password to remake the transaction. The attacker now has access to
> Gene’s wallet.

I quite don't get how an attacker uses the open tabs to see that Gene is using Metamask.

I'd appreciate it if you explain this a little bit further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Metamask v7, the wallet extension was sharing the user selected address with every opened tabs. That means, any websites opened through these tabs could possibly track the user's transactions history and the amount of ethers/tokens held by the wallet. A malicious website could simulate the Metamask behavior by sending the user fake pop-up/notifications.

For example, the attacker could wait for the user to send a transaction and then inject a scam pop-up acting in the following way :

- tell the transaction has failed and ask the user to sign a new one where the recipient address is the hacker address.
- tell the user a problem has occurred and the wallet has disconnected, then ask him to enter his seed (which is needed to recover the wallet) to re-connect and process the transaction.

A novice user could be trapped by this kind of attack.

Since the v7, Metamask no longer shares the account address to visited websites without the user's consent, who must manually confirm their willingness to interact with the site.

Comment: Hi clement, appreciate the answer, however I might have the same kind of questions since I quite don't get the actual scenario. So, let's say I have 3 tabs open. `facebook.com, instagram.com, malicious.com`.  How could `malicious.com` track metamask's wallet's balance ? is there a code for that ? and how could `malicious.com` detect when user would make a transaction with metamask ? and also, why on earth would metamask give balance and history to each tab ?

Comment: `How could malicious.com track metamask's wallet's balance ?` Metamask was injecting the account address into the navigator (more info here : https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6325). Then `malicious.com` can simply see the address information (transacions history, balances, etc) using Etherscan for example. Hopefully this has been fixed now.

Comment: Metamask only communicates the address, not transactions history and balances. But  knowing an address one can track these informations, using something like Etherscan.

Comment: So metamask would put the user's address in `navigator` object of `window` . Then malicious.com website could just get it from `navigator`, right ? .. How would `malicious.com` figure out that user made a transaction in real time so that it has to quickly show up its own popup ? does it make requests to etherscan every 1 second ?

Comment: I guess you can manage this with Etherscan API, or some web3 functions such as `getTransactionCount` for exemple.

Comment: Understood. So i guess malicious website would make that request to etherscan every 1 second to quickly figure out if user made new transaction. doesn't etherscan API disallow this ? making such quick requests ? and if malicious website make requests every 10 seconds, then it would be much more time than the transaction actually needs.  What do you think ? and also I guess user has to be subscribed to push notifications on `malicious.com` website, but it's interesting that the popup would never look the same as metamask since browser push notifications can't exactly mimic the style design.

Comment: Honestly I don't know much about Etherscan API. Even if his tx has been mined, a novice user could be trapped by a pop-up saying it was not. Also it is possible to show an identical Metamask pop-up by copying the css.

Comment: Any idea why metamask needed to put address in `navigator` ? and also if one site puts something in navigator, second site can't see that value in the navigator. how is this different from metamask case ?

Comment: This can be useful for dApps.

Comment: if one site puts something in navigator, second site can't see that value in the navigator. how does it work then in metamask case ?